# Getting RSSIValue from IOBluetoothHostController

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to write a simple application that gathers the RSSIValue and displays it via NSLog, my code is as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> 
#import <IOBluetooth/objc/IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry.h>
#import <IOBluetooth/objc/IOBluetoothDevice.h>
#import <IOBluetooth/objc/IOBluetoothHostController.h>
#import <IOBluetooth/IOBluetoothUtilities.h>

@interface getRSSI: NSObject {}
-(void) readRSSIForDeviceComplete:(id)controller device:(IOBluetoothDevice*)device 
                             info:(BluetoothHCIRSSIInfo*)info error:(IOReturn)error; 
@end

@implementation getRSSI
- (void) readRSSIForDeviceComplete:(id)controller device:(IOBluetoothDevice*)device 
                              info:(BluetoothHCIRSSIInfo*)info error:(IOReturn)error
{
    if (error != kIOReturnSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"readRSSIForDeviceComplete return error");
        CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
    }
    if (info->handle == kBluetoothConnectionHandleNone) {
        NSLog(@"readRSSIForDeviceComplete no handle");
        CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
    }
    NSLog(@"RSSI = %i dBm ", info->RSSIValue);
    [NSThread sleepUntilDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 5]];
    [device closeConnection];
    [device openConnection];
    [controller readRSSIForDevice:device];
}
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) { 
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
    NSLog(@"start"); 

    IOBluetoothHostController *hci = [IOBluetoothHostController defaultController];
    NSString *addrStr = @"xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx";
    BluetoothDeviceAddress addr;
    IOBluetoothNSStringToDeviceAddress(addrStr, &addr);
    IOBluetoothDevice *device = [[IOBluetoothDevice alloc] init];
    device = [IOBluetoothDevice withAddress:&addr];
    [device retain];
    [device openConnection];
    getRSSI *rssi = [[getRSSI alloc] init];
    [hci setDelegate:rssi];
    [hci readRSSIForDevice:device];
    CFRunLoopRun();
    [hci release];
    [rssi release];
    [pool release]; 
    return 0; 
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the readRSSIForDeviceComplete seems to work just fine, info passes along a value. The problem is that the RSSI value is drastically different from the one I can view from OS X via option clicking the bluetooth icon at the top. It is typical for my application to print off 1,2,-1,-8,etc while the menu displays -64 dBm, -66, -70, -42, etc.

I would really appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The value you get from readRSSIForDeviceComplete is the RSSI value. The value shown via OS X when option/alt-clicking the BlueTooth menu is the **Raw** RSSI value.

Assuming you have the Developer Tools you can see both values by using "Bluetooth Explorer" (/Developer/Applications/Bluetooth/Bluetooth Explorer). I have no idea what meaningful difference there is between the two values but for me they seem to constantly differ by a value of -60.

So your RSSI values of 1, 2, -1, -8 would correspond to Raw RSSI values of -59, -58, -61, -68.